# how to identify when a dynamic element is ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to identify when a dynamic element is ready or when `$('root').append("<span id=\"child\"></span>");` is loaded, so that I can load another element within `child` element.

Currently I have:

```js
$('root').after("<span id=\"child\"></span>");
setTimeout(function(){
  $('#child').append("<h1>brah</h1>");
}, 1000);
```

While the above solution does work, 1 second is too long to wait for each element. And if I set the timer to 0, it become inconsistent.

Is there any better way to identify when a DOM is fully loaded?

Comment: That method of document modification is synchronous, am I missing something here?

Comment: @robinsax not sure what exactly synchronous here mean, but based on google, the server do not update the javascript code.

Comment: What is `root`? Does it exist in the document when that code runs?

Comment: @slappy, yep, `root` totally exist.

Comment: So you have an HTML element named `<root>`? And your code runs *after* that element has loaded? You don't exactly have a full working example in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the `child` element as a variable like this:

```
var child = $('<span id="child"></span>');

$('root').append(child);

child.append("<h1>brah</h1>");
```

After appending, you can use it to append another child element immediately, no need to delay,

Answer (score 0):

Just pass a callback to `.append`, and load your other element.

```js
$('#root').append("<span id=\"child\"></span>", () => {
  // Your code here!
});
```

Comment: getting this console error: `TypeError: html.replace is not a functionjquery.js:5822:15`

Comment: I think you'll have to make it `#root` or `.root`, depending upon if it's an id or a class.

Comment: @RohanMukherjee: The `.append()` method doesn't accept a callback function after the selector, because there would be no need for it to do so.

Comment: Of course it does, https://www.javatpoint.com/jquery-append, @slappy

Comment: No, it really doesn't. Why would it? Not sure what that site is, but it's definitely not jQuery's documentation. Here's the official docs: https://api.jquery.com/append/